# Check and remove multiple null values using ruby filter

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to write a filter that can check and remove multiple null value fields.

For instance,

```
filter {
  mutate {
   remove_tag => [ "foo_%{somefield}" ] }
}
```

but I need to do this check for many fields inside the json, so I would like to avoid using multiple if conditions. 
Searching on Google I found this

```
ruby {
    code => "event.to_hash.delete_if {|field, value| value == 'null' }"
 }
```

but it's not working and I am not really sure how this work. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through all the fields and check if value is `nil` (null in ruby); remove the `key` if it is `nil`.

This ruby filter will work,

```
ruby {
    code => "
        hash = event.to_hash
        hash.each do |key,value|
            if value == nil
                event.remove(key)
            end
        end
    "
}
```

Please let me know if it helps.